# How to set different dictkey name based on what I'm iterating through?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dictionary

I would like to ask for some suggestions how to properly handle my data, and at the end, export them into DataFrame.
I use pymol but the problem is general, not programme specific. Background: I have these structures and I want to extract information about their "resname". My final aim is to have pandas dataframe where there will be columns named by each of the "codes".
I have this script:

```
import pymol
import pandas as pd

codes = "2J28, 3BBX, 3J5L"

ID = codes.split(", ")
for IDS in ID:
    dir_path = "home/mydata/"
    structure= dir_path + "{}.pdb".format(IDS)
    cmd.load(structure)
    myspace = {"pdbs": []}
    my_info = cmd.iterate('(all and name P)', 'pdbs.append(resname)', space=myspace)
    print(myspace)
```

As result I get:

```
{'pdbs': ['A', 'G',...]}
{'pdbs': ['A', 'G',...]}
{'pdbs': ['A', 'G',...]}
```

Of course, I dont want each dictkey be named "pdbs" but by the corresponding code like this:

```
{'2J28': ['A', 'G',...]}
{'3BBX': ['A', 'G',...]}
{'3J5L': ['A', 'G',...]}
```

I tried set it directly:

```
myspace = {"{}".format(IDS): []}
my_info = cmd.iterate('(all and name P)', '"{}".format(IDS).append(resname)', space=myspace)
```

However, this doesnt work, problem seems to be in `'"{}".format(IDS).append(resname)`

Can anyone suggets how I can fix this problem, please?
Then I can append "myspace" of each code into one DataFrame.
Thank you

Comment: Can you please show some runnable code?

Answer (score 0):

I didn't check the code in detail, but what about just changing the last line to:

```
print({IDS: myspace['pdbs']})
```